# WSO2 ESB 4.7.0 UI does not allow editing any further after a JMS consumer is created

Tags: wso2-esb

I have the following JMS consumer proxy service defined:

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="DefiDealerProxy" transports="jms" statistics="enable" trace="enable" startOnLoad="true">
  <target>
    <inSequence>
      <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING" />
    </inSequence>
  </target>
  <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactory">myTopicConnectionFactory</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">activemq.topic.sync</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.jms.DestinationType">topic</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.jms.MessageSelector">ACTION = 'Save' AND ENTITY = 'dealer'</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.jms.SubscriptionDurable">true</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.jms.DurableSubscriberName">My Subscriber</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">
    <rules>
      <jmsProperty>contentType</jmsProperty>
      <default>application/xml</default>
    </rules>
  </parameter>
</proxy>
```

And here is my axis2.xml configuration:

```
<transportReceiver name="jms" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSListener">
  <parameter name="myTopicConnectionFactory" locked="false">
    <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</parameter>
    <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">failover:tcp://localhost:61616</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.UserName">user</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.Password">password</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">TopicConnectionFactory</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">topic</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.DurableSubscriberClientID" locked="false">myHomePC</parameter>
  </parameter>

  <parameter name="myQueueConnectionFactory" locked="false">
    <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</parameter>
    <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">failover:tcp://localhost:61616</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.UserName">user</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.Password">password</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">QueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.DurableSubscriberClientID" locked="false">myHomePC</parameter>
  </parameter>

  <parameter name="default" locked="false">
    <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</parameter>
    <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">failover:tcp://localhost:61616</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.UserName">user</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.Password">password</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">QueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.DurableSubscriberClientID" locked="false">myHomePC</parameter>
  </parameter>
</transportReceiver>
```

Once I create the proxy service in source mode and save it.  It successfully connects to the ActiveMQ broker and receives messages as expected.  However, I cannot edit the proxy service again in design or source mode as the UI completely changes upon clicking the Edit button.  I have facing this issue in ESB 4.6 & 4.7.  Has anyone faced this issue?  any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the single quotes inside `<parameter name="transport.jms.MessageSelector">ACTION = 'Save' AND ENTITY = 'dealer'</parameter>` line is causing the issue.

I was able to get an editable proxy service using the following configuration.

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="DefiDealerProxy"
       transports="jms"
       statistics="enable"
       trace="enable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">
      <rules>
         <jmsProperty>contentType</jmsProperty>
         <default>application/xml</default>
      </rules>
   </parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.MessageSelector">ACTION=Save AND ENTITY = dealer</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactory">myTopicConnectionFactory</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.DestinationType">topic</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">activemq.topic.sync</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.DurableSubscriberName">My Subscriber</parameter>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```